# Ubuntu 22.04 stays in eternal loop at reboot / restart

Tags: boot

After the systems welcomes me in Ubuntu 22.04 it continues and after the last (OK) Finished  Terminator Plymouth Boot Screen message appears the the next messsages are all
(FAILED) Failed tot start:

- Tool to automatically collect and Submit kernel crash signatures
- Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.
- Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer
- Network Name Resolution
- Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.

and then it repeats the same messsages.

Comment: Reboot in Restoration Mode (tap ESC once when PC manufacturer's logo shows on screen - if it goes straight to grub> then "exit"  and tap ESC once immediately) select root from dropdown options, then cd /var, then ls -a to look for logs folder then select right-looking file name.  Copy out log data for boot up process and paste into your OP.